# RuntimeError: reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedWriter name='<stderr>'> on gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn, stderr, worker

Someone can help me with the error below?

If I run the code directly from shell the sever works fine and I can see the page on browser.
But if I run the systemd service I've got this error:

```
 RuntimeError: reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedWriter name='<stderr>'>
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]: Traceback (most recent call last):
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1082, in emit
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/home/pi/tserver/tserver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     self.reap_workers()
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/home/pi/tserver/tserver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 530, in reap_workers
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     self.log.warning(
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/home/pi/tserver/tserver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/glogging.py", line 261, in warning
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     self.error_log.warning(msg, *args, **kwargs)
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1454, in warning
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     self._log(WARNING, msg, args, **kwargs)
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1585, in _log
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     self.handle(record)
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1595, in handle
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     self.callHandlers(record)
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1657, in callHandlers
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     hdlr.handle(record)
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 948, in handle
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     self.emit(record)
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1087, in emit
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     self.handleError(record)
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1000, in handleError
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     sys.stderr.write('--- Logging error ---\n')
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]: RuntimeError: reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedWriter name='<stderr>'>
dic 02 08:27:23 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]: Call stack:
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/home/pi/tserver/tserver/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     sys.exit(run())
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/home/pi/tserver/tserver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/home/pi/tserver/tserver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     super().run()
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/home/pi/tserver/tserver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     Arbiter(self).run()
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/home/pi/tserver/tserver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 210, in run
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     self.murder_workers()
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/home/pi/tserver/tserver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in murder_workers
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     if time.time() - worker.tmp.last_update() <= self.timeout:
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/home/pi/tserver/tserver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     self.reap_workers()
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/home/pi/tserver/tserver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 530, in reap_workers
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     self.log.warning(
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:   File "/home/pi/tserver/tserver/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/glogging.py", line 261, in warning
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]:     self.error_log.warning(msg, *args, **kwargs)
dic 02 08:27:24 krokipysala gunicorn[4884]: Message: 'Worker with pid %s was terminated due to signal %s'
```

The code is running on a Raspberry Pi zero 1.1W if help.
Recently I've change the hostname of the Raspberry, it can causes this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to some other issue. Check the initial logs. I faced the same issue and later noticed an initial error related to new database not present in production postgres.